# Exportar SAS EG para Mysql por CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, exportação, sas

Tenho uma macro que exporta um arquivo CSV para o MySql. Já executei o "LOAD DATA LOCAL ..." pelo prompt do mysql e funciona perfeitamente.

```
%macro exportar_csv_mysql (host, usuario, senha, banco);

/*Cria csv da tabela SAS*/
%ds2csv (
   data=work.minha_tabela, 
   runmode=b, 
   csvfile='/dados/arquivo.csv'
 );

/*Limpa a tabela de destino*/
x /.mysql -h&host -u&usuario -p&senha -D&banco -e "TRUNCATE tb_destino";

/*Exporta o arquivo para mysql*/
x /.mysql -h&host -u&usuario -p&senha -D&banco --local-infile=1 -e  
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dados/arquivo.csv' 
 INTO TABLE tb_destino
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 IGNORE 1 LINES 
 (COLUNA_01, COLUNA_02, COLUNA_03, COLUNA_04, COLUNA_05, COLUNA_06,
 COLUNA_07, COLUNA_08, COLUNA_09, COLUNA_10, COLUNA_11, COLUNA_12, 
 COLUNA_13, COLUNA_14, COLUNA_15, COLUNA_16, COLUNA_17, COLUNA_18)";

%mend exportar_csv_mysql;
```

No SAS Enterprise Guide, até cria o .csv e executa o "TRUNCATE", mas a outra parte nem chega a executar e retorna o erro abaixo. O que estou fazendo de errado?

> "WARNING 32-169: The quoted string currently being processed has become
>   more than 262 characters long. You may have unbalanced quotation
>   marks."

Answer (score 1):

O SAS está reclamando porque sua "variável" está grande demais.

Use a opçao NOQUOTELENMAX ([http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002233891.htm][1])